# How to resize (shrink) images without increasing their filesize?

Tags: resizing, irfanview

I have a bunch of lossless optimized png's which I want to resize/shrink. Whenever I try to resize them the filesize is actually getting bigger. I've tried Imagemagick and Irfanview. This kinda doesn't make any sense to me. Since I'm more comfortable with Irfanview than Imagemagick I'm asking for a solution for Irfanview.

Any ideas?

---

Version: Irfanview 4.40 64bit on Windows 10

My Irfanview options for resize and save.

[image: Resize options]

[image: Save options]

Comment: ...yeah, that really doesn't make sense. the file size should decrease. My solution has always been to just drag it into gimp, resize it, and then export it again.

Comment: can you post an example png? maybe your image are 8bit indexed color and irfanview saves as 24bit RGB.

Comment: You say they were originally “optimized”. You did use something like PNGGauntlet afterwards, right?

Answer (score 1):

I use GIMP under Linux, but looking at your settings, you may want to get rid of the transparency layer (if its not required for the image), but more importantly, under "size method" choose "resize".

What is probably happening is that the down-sampled image has a lot more colors and information because its antialising the image to give it a smoother look.